# Retrieving Id attribute of dynamically generated checkboxes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am dynamically creating UI from codebehind. The UI is placed in a content place holder in which contains checkbox images with a name under it. The names are coming from SQL.

```
    Try
        Dim QryCount As String = "query to retrieve the data"
        Dim TblCount As DataTable = connection.GetDataTable(QryCount, sqlcon)
        Dim count As Integer
        count = TblCount.Rows.Count
        If count <> 0 Then
            For Each RowCount As DataRow In TblCount.Rows
                str= RowCount("str_name").ToString()
                Hit_count = RowCount("Download_Count").ToString()
                TT = RowCount("ToolTip").ToString()
                u_id = RowCount("id").ToString()

                URLData1 = URLData1 & "<input type='checkbox' runat='server' id='check" & u_id & "'/><label for='check" & u_id & "'> <img src='images.png'/><br><a href='simple.aspx?ID=" & u_id & "'title='" & TT & "' target='_blank'>" & str & "</a><span style='font-size: 8pt; font-family:segoe ui;color: #3399FF;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;[" & Hit_count & "]</span>
```

Next
`lblCol4.Text = URLData1`

and the ui page contains the code as

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnsubmit" Text="Submit" />
    </div>


<div class="columns">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCol4" runat="server" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="Small" style="text-align: center"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

It is a multiselection checkboxes. Once the user selects and click on the submit button I am trying to read the selected checkbox id attributes so that I can retrieve the corresponding data from SQL. I am new to asp.net.Please help me

Comment: Please share your current javascript code which you have tried.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

                var ids = '';
                $('#Content2 input:checked').each(function () { ids += this.id + ',' });
                alert(ids);

               
                //  window.location.href = 'url_you_want_to_navigate?ids=' + ids;

                return false;

            });

        }); `

Comment: for now i am just trying to check whether I can read them .this code is working for static UI but not for dynamic UI

Comment: What is the error you are getting in dynamic UI? Try adding some breakpoints using `debugger;` statement and check in the developer console of your browser.

Comment: Actually I am trying to fetch the id's of checkbox after selection from user.for the script i have written is not showing anything.the same script is working for static UI